# HTTP.get function synchronously execution in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, get

I have to call HTTP. get function synchronously so that it will wait until its response didn't come. it should not go to execute next line until below line executes. Where I am wrong please help me out

```
this.classCheck.checkD().then(present => present ? console.log("Present==true  " + present) : console.log(" Present==false  " + present));

async checkD() {
    let present: boolean = true;
    let status : number;
    const res = await this.http.get(url,{ headers: header, observe:'response'}).toPromise().then( response => {
      console.log(response.status);
      status = response.status;
    });
    
    if(status >= 400) {
      present = false;
    }
    return present;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Actually, that one is not for synchronous calls it is just getting the response irrespective of the call sequence

Answer (score 0):

You need to await on your promise. You or await or `.then`.
One is synchronous, the other asynchronous.

```
async checkD() {
    let present: boolean = true;
    let status : number;
    const res = await this.http.get(url,{ headers: header, observe:'response'}).toPromise();
    status = res.status;
    if(status >= 400) {
      present = false;
    }
    return present;
}
```

Comment: This is giving an error. i think it is because we are extracting status from promise in the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe, but this has nothing to do with your question. await a promise is done the way I showed you. Just console log res and you will see what you can do to follow